# Bind installed team fortress 2 game to steam

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I've downloaded and installed tf2 from the internet, but it couldn't connect to online servers. So I've also installed steam after that.

Now when I want to play tf2 from inside the steam, it doesn't see the existing installation and wants to download tf2 anew. Can I anyway make steam use the already installed game?

Comment: ...Why didn't you download it through Steam in the first place?

Comment: @fbueckert: I wanted to avoid 12gb download, because offline installer is much smaller

Comment: I don't see how an offline installer would be any smaller; it would still have to download and install everything.  Unless it was meant to just be played offline, in which case, defeats the entire purpose of TF2.

Comment: Installed from offline installer, the game folder is 11 gb, and the installer itself is much smaller.

Comment: Steam's downloads are compressed,  it just does not show it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try copying the game files to the appropriate folder in `steamapps`. I would think that Steam would recognize most of the files as the ones it is expecting.

The copy you would do is something along the lines of
`C:\Program Files\Valve\Team Fortress 2\  --->  C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\~grigorgevorgyan\team fortress 2\`

Of course, some of these files are bound to be wrong (like the .exe - the standalone won't have the Steam hooks). So, go to steam and tell it to "Verify Local Game Files..." and wait for it to redownload the different items.

Comment: Well, I thought a <kbd> would look cool, but apparently not.